# How to open multiple projects in VS Code with only one LSP connection?

Tags: visual-studio-code, vscode-calva

I have multiple projects (git-repos). I have opened these in one multi-root workspace using `Add Folder to Workspace...`. Since these are all Clojure projects, and I have `Calva` installed, VSCode identified the correct LSP server `clojure-lsp`. But VS Code starts one LSP server for each folder/project in my multi-root workspace. I want only one.

How can I tell VS Code to start only one LSP server for all folders in my workspace?

Answer (score 0):

At the time of this writing, this is not supported. See [multi root support? #280](https://github.com/clojure-lsp/clojure-lsp/issues/280). If you look at their [projects page](https://github.com/clojure-lsp/clojure-lsp/projects/1), that issue ticket is currently placed in the "Low priority" lane.

<sup><sub>[You can show your support for the issue ticket by giving a thumbs up reaction to the issue. But please *don't* make a "me too" comment.](https://github.com/microsoft/vscode/wiki/Submitting-Bugs-and-Suggestions) "me too" comments generally come off as annoying to repo maintainers because they clutter up discussion and don't contribute anything of significant value.</sub></sup>

Some quotes from the discussion there:

[lucywang000](https://github.com/clojure-lsp/clojure-lsp/issues/280#issue-793901499):

> I noticed that python's [pyright lsp](https://github.com/emacs-lsp/lsp-pyright) only fires up one instance for multiple python projects, would it make sense to have a similar feature in clojure-lsp?
>
> Some related quote from the doc (https://github.com/microsoft/pyright/blob/master/docs/configuration.md):
>
> ```
> Multi-root workspaces (“Add Folder to Workspace…”) are supported, and each workspace root can have its own “pyrightconfig.json” file.
> ```
>
> I used to open lots (5-10) of clojure/script projects, for e.g reading 3rdparty libs code. It doesn't make sense to have 10 lsp instances running and take up to 10-20GB of memory ...

[ericdallo](https://github.com/clojure-lsp/clojure-lsp/issues/280#issuecomment-767275876):

> Yeah, it sound a good idea, but I'm not sure this works for most of clients, including `lsp-mode` (lsp-clojure.el), it'd need some extra work on their side, and I'm no sure what need to be done on server side too

[bpringe](https://github.com/clojure-lsp/clojure-lsp/issues/280#issuecomment-769371182):

> I was thinking about this recently. I think this is a good idea, though I know it might take some time and thought to implement well.

[bpringe](https://github.com/clojure-lsp/clojure-lsp/issues/280#issuecomment-769372023):

> Another thing to consider is that *if* the memory usage of clojure-lsp can be drastically reduced via graalvm and other methods, this becomes less of a problem. I still think it's a worthwhile thing to do in any case, though.
>
> Edit: Linking [#229](https://github.com/clojure-lsp/clojure-lsp/issues/229)

[snoe](https://github.com/clojure-lsp/clojure-lsp/issues/280#issuecomment-769473884)

> I know some workplaces do multi repo/multi project/multi language stuff but it should be understood there's costs there, particularly around tooling support and it should be clear that those places should be investing in their tools.
>
> I think that comparing ourselves to things like intellij or vscode backed by huge companies and hundreds of devs is a losing proposition.
>
> So, in the end, my view is that collaboration and PRs can be welcome, but understand there's a high effort to maintain compatibility and performance and stability across servers and clients and to do the testing across those environments.

Comment: I have managed to configure multiple projects with only one clojure-lsp in Emacs. I am asking here if this is also possible in VSCode.

Comment: @Witek And I am telling you that according to discussion by the clojure-lsp maintainers, it is currently not configurable by users. That issue ticket is in reference to VS Code's multi-root workspaces feature. Isn't that exactly what your question is about?

Comment: I hoped for a creative solution. Like opening only one folder and linking / symlinking the others. Or blacklisting the start of LSP server for some folders like I did in Emacs. Or whatever is the way hacks are done in VS Code....

Answer (score 0):

To make one clojure-lsp serve all folders in your workspace, you can use a single deps.edn file at the top level that references the other projects as local dependencies.

[Clojure-lsp's repo](https://github.com/clojure-lsp/clojure-lsp) is an example of this. If I open this repo in Calva version 2.0.337 (the latest version at the time of this writing), only one clojure-lsp server is started.